# Is "Enumerate sites" out of beta?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

The Graph API docs mention that site enumeration is available in beta: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http That page is not available in v1.

**However**, when calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites` I got get a response, and, in fact, get almost all sites.

I'd like to know if site enumeration is indeed out of beta and safe to use in production apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to use beta endpoints in production apps. You can have a try below method to get all sites:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/113056/microsoft-graph-api-fetch-sharepoint-sites-new-sit.html

Comment: Thank you very, very much for that link, it works perfectly! So, to confirm: even though that endpoint is found under "v1.0", it's still in beta?

Comment: you can access it in V1.0, but that endpoint is undocumented.